# Cloud Functions for Firebase for existing data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I use Cloud Functions for Firebase database triggers to edit/update existing data?

My Use Case:
I have existing data in my Firebase database, say `a/{uid}/b`, at the time of writing, I have 14-15 uids in the db where `b` is already defined. Now I want to use cloud function to listen to write to `b` and add some more data based on that.

The database trigger `functions.database.ref('/a/{uid}/b').onWrite` will only execute for new writes/updates to the specific path, not for existing writes/updates.

How can Cloud Functions for Firebase help when I want to update all the data at once for existing write logics?

Comment: I'd create a separate function (HTTP or Database triggered, doesn't really matter) purely for the migration. Then again: you could also simply do that with a local node script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. I found a workaround to get the function executed. This is not ideal for production database but worked for me for a small database.

Export existing data from a collection ( or entire database ) into a file on which you have trigger functions.

Then delete the data that is exported from the database. ( Please be aware if you have onWrite function, it gets executed on delete as well. Make sure code handles it properly )

Command to export a collection

```
firestore-export --accountCredentials=/path/credentials.json --nodePath collectionName
```

Then import the backup data in the same collection using the command below.

```
firestore-import --accountCredentials=/path/credentials.json --backupFile /path/backupFilename.json --nodePath collectionName
```

More information about firebase-export npm package @
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export